# what style/attr/drawable for inverse background?

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to make a ExpandableListView where the group headers are drawn inverse. There is no problem with changing the text color, size etc. via XML. I even found out how to use the system defaults like

```
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse"
/>
```

But for the background color?! I don't understand why these styles don't include background color information?!

Of course I could use a direct color, but I look for good default background attributes or styles. Like "style/Background.For.TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse" ;-)

What would be a good solution? So that for the dark themed devices I get white/gray, and for the white themed I get black?

Or should I simply use R.color.background_light?

Greetings, Joerg

PS: First question here ;-) Thanx to all the people answering here the last months and years: You great people made it much more easier for me to find a re-entrance in programming after 12 years break ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As you observe, the styles with "TextAppearance" in their name only affect the foreground text attributes of the view.  They are appropriate for the `android:textAppearance` attribute.  The styles with "Widget" in their names define all the UI properties and will work in a `style` attribute, but Android doesn't define a "Widget.TextView.Inverse" style.

When I wanted to display an console-like log as an inverse text view, I used the following XML:

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
    android:background="?android:colorForeground"
    ... />
```

It uses the theme's foreground color as the background for the view.  With a dark theme it displays dark text on white, and in a light theme it displays light text on black.